# Programming - Condition using OR and reverse case

Tags: c#, programming-languages, conditional-statements

I use C#,
I have a conditional statement in my code.
I need to check a series o variables in a OR sequence.

Firstly I need to check if this expression is true.

```
original.RawFormat.Guid == SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png.Guid & newCodec == "image/png" ||
original.RawFormat.Guid == SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif.Guid & newCodec == "image/gif"
```

Secondly I also need to check a **Reverse Case** (hope I'm able to express myself with Reverse Case)

```
original.RawFormat.Guid == SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png.Guid & newCodec == "image/gif" ||
original.RawFormat.Guid == SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif.Guid & newCodec == "image/png"
```

At the moment I use this code (it is working).
But to me seems not very elegant, so I would like to know if exist a better way to accomplish the same.
I'm pretty new at coding, I would appreciate your examples.

Thanks guys for your help!!!!

---

```
// Clear New Image and add Transparent Background if codec input or optut allow trasparency.
if (original.RawFormat.Guid == SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png.Guid & newCodec == "image/png" ||
    original.RawFormat.Guid == SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif.Guid & newCodec == "image/gif" ||  
    original.RawFormat.Guid == SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png.Guid & newCodec == "image/gif" ||
    original.RawFormat.Guid == SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif.Guid & newCodec == "image/png")
{
    newImage.Clear(SD.Color.Transparent); // Apply Transparent Canvas.               
}
else
{
    // Translate htmlColor to a GDI+Color structure.
    SD.Color myColor = SD.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(backgroundColorHtml);
    // Clear Image and apply background color.
    newImage.Clear(myColor);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following also will work:

```
(original.RawFormat.Guid == SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png.Guid ||
 original.RawFormat.Guid == SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif.Guid) &&
(newCodec == "image/png" ||newCodec == "image/gif")
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, your code help me to understand... do you guys know other way to do it? So I can have a bigger picture?

Comment: @GibboK: It's a combination of understanding Boolean algebra: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra, and experience. In this particular case you wanted one thing from group A (the format) and one thing from group B (the codec). So the expression is, in essence, `if (A && B)`, where `A` checks to see if the format is correct and `B` checks to see if the codec is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Parentheses ( )` :

```
if ((original.RawFormat.Guid == SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png.Guid & (newCodec == "image/png" ||newCodec == "image/gif")) ||
    (original.RawFormat.Guid == SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif.Guid & (newCodec == "image/gif" ||newCodec == "image/png")))
```

or

```
if (((original.RawFormat.Guid == SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png.Guid)||
(original.RawFormat.Guid == SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif.Guid))&
(newCodec == "image/png" ||newCodec == "image/gif"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
if (new [] { SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png.Guid, SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif.Guid }.Contains(original.RawFormat.Guid)
    && Regex.IsMatch(newCodec, "^image/(png|gif)$")
```

Although, in production code I would split it up a bit:

```
var imageFormats = new [] { SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png.Guid, SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif.Guid };
if (imageFormats.Contains(original.RawFormat.Guid) && Regex.IsMatch(newCodec, "^image/(png|gif)$"))
```

Comment: Thanks Ferrucio your code it is really interesting.. but do not you think the Regex.Match could add overhead?

Comment: That `Regex.Match` is going to match `"uglyimage/pnggggggg!"`, as well as anything else that contains the substring `image/png` or `image/gif`. To be correct, it would need to be `^image/(png|gif)$`.

Comment: Anything you do will add a certain amount of overhead. The question is what is the overhead relative to the alternatives and does it matter in this context? If the code is performance critical then you should measure each alternative and pick the fastest. Otherwise, go for the code that will be easiest to read and maintain.